# Can I put an if statement inside a lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, swing, lambda

More specifically, I'm talking about for Java Swing where you would use a lambda expression for adding an ActionListener.

```
combobox.addActionListener(
    event -> {if (boolean) runMethod()});
```

I've tried compiling as written, but it didn't work so I'm wondering if such a flow of logic is just not allowed or if I just need to reword a few things.

Comment: add a semicolon after `runMethod()` and try again. Inside `{}` is a code block that needs them.

Comment: Do what @zapl said, and also you need an actual `boolean` variable/expression in your parentheses after the `if`...not the keyword.

Comment: Also, what IDE are you using? If you had this code in Eclipse or NetBeans, it would show a warning saying to insert a `;` to complete the statement. I'd suggest using a modern IDE, it saves a lot of headache.

Comment: Great it worked thanks! @JackmeriusTacktheritrix Sorry about the improper use of "compiling as written," I do have an actual statement in there =P

Comment: I use terminal haha.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix Is there any particular convention for how to write out all those ) and } at the end? ();}); seems like it would be hard to read at times.

Comment: Personally, I use braces for all of my if statements, even the one-liners that don't require it. I'd have the `if (boolean) {` on one line, the `runMethod()` on the next line, then the closing `}` on the next line. It just looks cleaner to me. That's just preference though. Some people would prefer to do it in fewer lines.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb60f94b7c9dba93d847 is how I'd format that most of the time

Comment: Note that if the boolean expression dies not call a method and is therefore effectively final, you can extract the if block from the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combobox.addActionListener(
    event -> {if (boolean) runMethod();});
```

Missing a semicolon.